# How to send broadcast data with Web Socket Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, broadcast

I need to send data from my BE to FE when an event happen, so I have created an Event Emitter and in the Fucntion i would like to send a Broadcast message to all the client (the message is an Array of Object), this is my code but unfortunately doesn't work properly.

```
emitter.on('readData', function(){
    wss.broadcast = function(data) {
        wss.clients.forEach(client => client.send(Object));
     };
    });
```

Comment: What WebSocket library are you using?

Comment: I'm using ws base library

Answer (score 0):

Ok instead of broadcasting, you are defining a function to broadcast.

```
emitter.on('readData', function(){
    wss.clients.forEach(client => client.send(Object));
});
```

More details [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#server-broadcast).